# Cassandra CPP "Connection pool was unable to connect to host"

Tags: c++, cassandra, datastax

I'm working on a project using the cassandra-cpp-driver from datastax (https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver). I'm currently writing an accessor. It was working a few days ago, but now whenever I try to execute a query, I get an error

```
1497993874.207 [ERROR] (src/pool.cpp:388:virtual void 
cass::Pool::on_close(cass::Connection*)): Connection pool was unable to 
connect to host xx.xx.xx.160 because of the following error: Connect error 
'host is unreachable'
```

My issue is that nowhere in my code or cassandra configuration am I connecting to anything with IP address xx.xx.xx.160. I have a four node cluster with IP addresses 211, 212, 213, and 159. 211 and 213 are seeds. As far as I know I've set up the cluster correctly. I'm able to access it using CQLSH and the python driver.

```
connect_future = NULL;
cluster = cass_cluster_new();
session = cass_session_new();
cass_cluster_set_contact_points(d_cluster,"xx.xx.xx.211,xx.xx.xx.213");
connect_future = cass_session_connect_keyspace(session, cluster, "test");
if (cass_future_error_code(connect_future) != CASS_OK) {
        std::cout << "Unable to connect";
}
CassError rc = CASS_OK;
CassStatement* statement = cass_statement_new(
            "INSERT INTO users (id, name) VALUES 
            (bigintAsBlob(8943750892347), 'George');", 0);
CassFuture* future = NULL;
future = cass_session_execute(session, statement);
cass_future_wait(future);
rc = cass_future_error_code(future);
if (rc != CASS_OK) {
    std::cout << "Error in query";
}
cass_future_free(future);
cass_statement_free(statement);
cass_future_free(connect_future);
cass_cluster_free(cluster);
cass_session_free(session);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you set the `broadcast_rpc_address` on each node to be the public interface? Usually when there is a mix of private and public interfaces this can happen as the driver reads the system peers table to retrieve information about the cluster and those IP addresses that it is determining might be the private interface IP addresses.

Comment: Figured out the problem - or at least I got the cluster to start working properly again. Somehow, the 160 was added to the cluster as a node (probably a typo on my part somewhere when setting everything up). However, since 160 didn't actually exist, it was seen as a dead node. Had to use nodetool to forcefully remove it.